# Regression line just in certain groups (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression

Hi I'm trying to add the regression line just to the Le and Aw groups. Try using subset but didnt work. Dont know what I may be doing wrong.
Here is my code:

```
# Set up the work directory in which all data is gonna be extracted
H1517 = read.csv("Test_Subsetv3.csv") #Change name of the file
# Load the ggplot2 package
library(ggplot2) #Run to create plots
library(grid)
library(cowplot)
library(gridExtra)

test <- ggplot(H1517,aes(PI,FE,color=factor(Seg)))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(data=subset(H1517,Seg==Le | 
  Seg==Aw),aes(PI,FE,color=factor(Seg)),method=lm,se=FALSE)

test
```

Then I get the next error:

> Error in eval(e, x, parent.frame()) : object 'Le' not found

```
test
```

> Error: object 'test' not found

**Data in `dput` format.**
The OP posted this example dataset in a comment.

```
H1517 <-
structure(list(FE = c(69.27030884, 60.62345885, 
59.87889173, 69.27030884, 60.62345885, 59.87889173, 
69.27030884, 60.62345885, 59.87889173, 71.11906144, 
69.27030884, 60.62345885, 59.87889173, 61.88615029, 
71.11906144, 69.27030884, 60.62345885, 59.87889173),
PI = c(0.203496781, 0.197520353, 0.209443661, 
0.110640382, 0.116677419, 0.10343242, 0.299820599,
 0.303724997, 0.261057467, 0.125785204, 0.237294948,
 0.249327695, 0.275266774, 0.300414044, 0.283862484,
 0.148747292, 0.13326041, 0.149232038),
 Seg = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L,
 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L),
 .Label = c("Aw", "Glu", "Le", "Pa", "Ra"),
 class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-18L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Should it be `subset(H1517, Seg=="Le" | Seg=="Aw")`?

Comment: @Lyngbakr Or maybe `subset(H1517, Seg %in% c("Le", "Aw"))`.

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(H1517)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(H1517, 20))`.

Comment: FE  PI Seg
69.27030884 0.203496781 Glu
60.62345885 0.197520353 Glu
59.87889173 0.209443661 Glu
69.27030884 0.110640382 Pa
60.62345885 0.116677419 Pa
59.87889173 0.10343242 Pa
69.27030884 0.299820599 Le
60.62345885 0.303724997 Le
59.87889173 0.261057467 Le
71.11906144 0.125785204 Pa
69.27030884 0.237294948 Aw
60.62345885 0.249327695 Aw
59.87889173 0.275266774 Aw
61.88615029 0.300414044 Le
71.11906144 0.283862484 Le
69.27030884 0.148747292 Ra
60.62345885 0.13326041 Ra
59.87889173 0.149232038 Ra

Comment: @RuiBarradas I try with your way and this came up: Error: `mapping` must be created by `aes()`

Comment: No!!! Edit the **question**, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me.

```
test <- ggplot(H1517, aes(PI, FE, color = Seg)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(data = subset(H1517, Seg %in% c("Le", "Aw")),
              aes(PI, FE, color = Seg),
              method = lm, se = FALSE)

test
```

[image]

**Data.**

```
H1517 <-
structure(list(FE = c(69.27030884, 60.62345885, 
59.87889173, 69.27030884, 60.62345885, 59.87889173, 
69.27030884, 60.62345885, 59.87889173, 71.11906144, 
69.27030884, 60.62345885, 59.87889173, 61.88615029, 
71.11906144, 69.27030884, 60.62345885, 59.87889173),
PI = c(0.203496781, 0.197520353, 0.209443661, 
0.110640382, 0.116677419, 0.10343242, 0.299820599,
 0.303724997, 0.261057467, 0.125785204, 0.237294948,
 0.249327695, 0.275266774, 0.300414044, 0.283862484,
 0.148747292, 0.13326041, 0.149232038),
 Seg = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L,
 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L),
 .Label = c("Aw", "Glu", "Le", "Pa", "Ra"),
 class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-18L), class = "data.frame")
```